# I hear always to use prepared statements, but in what about wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Question 1. I know I don't need to do them for `wbdb->insert` or `wbpdb->delete`, but people say do it anyway even though the class will do it for you.

```
// I've got a select count query function and should use it here.

global $wpdb;
$entries = $wpdb->prefix . 'simpledir_entries';
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $entries WHERE rel = $id;");

if($count <= 0){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

Question 2. I'm not sure how to formulate this into the proper prepared statement which is completely secured. Does $entries and $id both need it?

Thanks

Comment: You could validate that **$id** is numeric - `if (is_numeric($id))` ... then proceed - else die

Comment: `$entries` should be whitelisted then passed in. `$id` should be bound. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your first question: Prepare statement in WordPress prepares a SQL query for safe execution. It uses sprintf()-like syntax.

For your second question: In your case of `get_var` query the statement should be something like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$entries = $wpdb->prefix . 'simpledir_entries';
$count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %s WHERE rel = %d;", $entries, $id));

if($count <= 0){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

Good Luck!!